# laravel query settings table without raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have several tables that stores form data. Most of the form field data stores in a settings table. So those field ids are stored in those several tables.

eg:

```
----------------------------------
|Videography                     |
----------------------------------
|id | width | height | equipment |
----------------------------------
|1  |  1    |     2  |    3      |
----------------------------------

-------------------------------
|Form settings                |
-------------------------------
|id | label        |     value|
-------------------------------
|1  |  some_label  |     1024 |
|2  |  some_label  |      728 |
|3  |  some_label  |    Camera|  
-------------------------------
```

I need a method to get string values (form fields) from those form data tables. I know I can use table joins. But is there a method to get this type of relation data using Eloquent?

Required output

```
 videography:{
     id:1,
     width:1024,
     height:728,
     equipment:camera
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you @ManishYadav. I have added that

Comment: Nope, you this is not possible using Eloquent's default functionality. You will need to use table joins. As Eloquent's relation works on table but you are trying to create relations on data, which is not possible right now

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks @ManishYadav

Comment: Have you checked [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) ?
It will not return same result with joins but you can get the settings with a syntax like $row->width->setting->label, $row->width->setting->value etc.